# Terraform handling multiple nested counts

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

Trying to assign azure rbac roles for resource level. For that I'm getting the details of the resource name/rg name and the type .

**My Folder Structure**

```
.
├── aad_permissions_assignments
│   ├── main.tf (module which just calls the aad-group-generic-roles folder
│   └── output.tf
│   ├── aad_permissions_assignments.tfvars
│   
|   
├── aad-group-generic-roles
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── output.tf
```

**aad_permissions_assignments.tfvars** (Maintfvars file)

```
aad_permissions_assignments = [
    {
        group_display_name = "Platform Developers Group"

        resource_roles = [
            {
                role_name = "Reader"
                resourcegroup_name = "myRG"
                resource_name = "testblabla"
                resource_type = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    
            }            
        ] 
    },
    {            
        group_display_name = "Platform Admin Group"

        resource_roles = [
            {
                role_name = "Reader"
                resourcegroup_name = "myRG2"
                resource_name = "testblabla21"
                resource_type = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    
            }            
        ] 
    }

   ]
```

**aad_permissions_assignments_generic** Module file

```
module "aad_permissions_assignments_generic" {

  source = "../aad-group-generic-roles"

  for_each = { for roleassignments in "${var.aad_permissions_assignments}" : roleassignments.group_display_name => roleassignments }    

  group_display_name = "${each.value.group_display_name}"
  resource_roles = "${each.value.resource_roles}"
}
```

**aad-group-generic-roles file**

```
data "azurerm_resources" "role_scope_resource" {
  count = "${length(var.resource_roles)}"

  resource_group_name = "${lookup(var.resource_roles[count.index], "resourcegroup_name")}"
  name = "${lookup(var.resource_roles[count.index], "resource_name")}"
  type = "${lookup(var.resource_roles[count.index], "resource_type")}"
}

 //Actual role assignment

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "generic_resource_assignment" {
  count = "${length(var.resource_roles)}"

  scope = "${element(data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource.resources.*.id, count.index)}"
  role_definition_name = "${lookup(var.resource_roles[count.index], "role_name")}"
  principal_id = "${element(data.azuread_group.security_group.*.id, count.index)}"
}
```

The problem I'm hitting is while calculating the scope of the of the resource id, Since `azurerm_resources` will return a list, but I always need to get the zero index of the resource out of it. As I need to tackle 3 loops overall here.

- One from tfvars `aad_permissions_assignments` group level
- two from the `resource_roles`
- Three from the `azurerm_resources`and the list of resources

When I try to run I get the error like

> Error: Missing resource instance key
>
> ine 42, in
> resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "generic_resource_assignment":
> 42:   scope =
> "${element(data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource.resources.*.id,
> count.index)}"
>
> Because data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource has "count" set,
> its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
>
> For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
> data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource[count.index]

Which is telling me to provide the correct instance, I have to choose always the zero index for my first resource. So I updated the line like

```
  scope = "${element(data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource.resources[0].*.id, count.index)}"
```

But still i get the same error

Error: Missing resource instance key

> in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "generic_resource_assignment":
> 42:   scope =
> "${element(data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource.resources[0].*.id,
> count.index)}"
>
> Because data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource has "count" set,
> its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
>
> For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
> data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource[count.index]

---

### Update : 1

Trying to get the output of `data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource`

**aad-group-generic-roles folder**

```
output "test" {
    value = "${data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource}"
}
```

**aad_permissions_assignments folder**

```
output "testparent" {
    value = "${module.aad_permissions_assignments_generic.test}"
}
```

Now getting an error like

> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on outputs.tf line 2, in output "testparent":    2: value =
> "${module.aad_permissions_assignments_generic.test}"
> |----------------
> | module.aad_permissions_assignments_generic is object with 2 attributes
>
> This object does not have an attribute named "test".

---

### Update 2

This is my output for the `data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource`

```
{
  "id" = "resource-2a235b3a-d832-4eab-8202-d64f9bf3789d"
  "name" = "mystorageacc"
  "resource_group_name" = "rg-01"
  "resources" = [
    {
      "id" = "/subscriptions/9xcxcxcxcxcx/resourceGroups/rg-01/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageacc"
      "location" = "eastus2"
      "name" = "mystorageacc"
      "type" = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    },
  ]
  "type" = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
}
```

Comment: pretty sure I'm not using for_each anywhere except on the `module aad_permissions_assignments_generic` which is the very top level loop for `aad_permissions_assignments`

Comment: I see. Can you provide example output from `data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource`? I think I know what is the issue.

Comment: Can you try with: `scope = "element(data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource[*].resources.id, count.index)}`?

Comment: Error: Unsupported attribute for the `id` data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource[*].resources.*id* .This value does not have any attributes.

Comment: Then it would be good idea to actually see the full form of `data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource`.

Comment: Ok Is there a easy way to print the `data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource` ?since it will give a list of values

Comment: You can output it `output "test" {value = data.azurerm_resources.role_scope_resource}`

Comment: I did this in the aad-group-generic-roles file now struggling to get back into my caller `aad_permissions_assignments_generic` module file. I tried like this in the modules output `output "testparent" {value = module.aad_permissions_assignments_generic.test}`but getting error like "This object does not have an attribute named "test"."

Comment: Sorry, but your question is getting very confusing. What module? What is `aad_permissions_assignments_generic`? Your question does not detail these modules or options.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i updated my OP with folder structure details. if you see that I actually added your output code inside the aad-group-generic-roles-> output.tf. However I'm running my terraform on `aad_permissions_assignments` folder level. So I need to capture the output from the child folder and pass on to the parent folder, which is what I struct at now

Comment: What are the new `output` values that you added in the `aad-group-generic-roles` and `aad_permissions_assignments`?

Comment: provided the *Update 1* in my POST with the details which you asked. on the other hand here is the properties of [azurerm_resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/resources)

Comment: In  your `module "aad_permissions_assignments_generic"` you are using `for_each`. So have to refer to its outputs using key notation, .e.g `module.aad_permissions_assignments_generic["some_key"].text`.

Comment: @Marcin I have provided the output which you asked in the *update 2* OP